# Efficient way to split two UTF-8 bytes from one another

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have two UTF-8 bytes `\xf0\x9f\x93\xb1\xf0\x9f\x9a\xac` and I want to split it like `\xf0\x9f\x93\xb1`, `\xf0\x9f\x9a\xac`what is the most efficient way to do this

What I am doing now is to split at `\xf0`

**Issue**

If I decode and encode it again as suggested by bigOTHER I get wrong byte back

```
>>> s ='\xf0\x9f\x93\xb1\xf0\x9f\x9a\xac'
>>> u = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> u
u'\U0001f4f1\U0001f6ac'
>>> u[0].encode("utf-8")
'\xed\xa0\xbd'
>>> u[1].encode("utf-8")
'\xed\xb3\xb1'
>>> u[0]
u'\ud83d'
>>> u[1]
u'\udcf1'
```

**Resolved:**

This is because My python is compiled with UCS2 instead of UCS4 while former being the default. For more info check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851069/decode-encode-utf-8-doesnt-lead-to-the-original-unicode)

Comment: what's your computer local?

Comment: @bigOTHER uhh.. what does that mean exactly?

Comment: lang_country.encoding

Comment: @bigOTHER bear with me but I don't know how to get UTF-8 collation used

Comment: Its a strange result that you had, I can't reproduce your results so I suggest to ask it as a new question like why decode-encode dont lead to the original unicode as in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use decode-encode to do it:

```
>>> u = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> u
u'\U0001f4f1\U0001f6ac '
>>> u[0].encode("utf-8")
'\xf0\x9f\x93\xb1'
>>> u[1].encode("utf-8")
'\xf0\x9f\x9a\xac'
```

Comment: I get a different response than yours `>>> u[0].encode("utf-8")
'\xed\xa0\xbd'` is this related to python version as I am using 2.7

Comment: what you get for `u`? and for both u[0].encode and u[1].encode?

Comment: I got `u` same as yours `>>> u = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> u
u'\U0001f4f1\U0001f6ac'`

Comment: `u[0]` and `u[1]` what gets you?

Comment: @Harwee I checked that you got answer for the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33851156/1327005,  Please consider to mark both questions as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Use the decode method. It splits it into bytes itself. So you can access directly after the call to decode.