# decode-encode UTF-8 doesn't lead to the original unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, decoding

When I am trying to separate two Unicode characters by decoding and encoding them again I do not get the same Unicode in return but I get a different one.

Attached are the responses when I try to do so.

```
>>> s ='\xf0\x9f\x93\xb1\xf0\x9f\x9a\xac'
>>> u = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> u
u'\U0001f4f1\U0001f6ac'
>>> u[0].encode("utf-8")
'\xed\xa0\xbd'
>>> u[1].encode("utf-8")
'\xed\xb3\xb1'
>>> u[0]
u'\ud83d'
>>> u[1]
u'\udcf1'
```

Comment: `u.encode('utf-8')` gives you the original bytes back

Comment: @Harwee it works fine for me - linux, python 2.7.10

Comment: @furas On Mac with python 2.7.10, I get the same results as the OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of python is using UCS-2 (16 bits per character) but these particular unicode characters require 32 bits, so element of u represents "half" of a character.  `u.encode('utf-8')` works properly because it understanding the encoding.

Your utf-8 string encodes these two characters:

`U+1F4F1 MOBILE PHONE character` (📱)

`U+1F6AC SMOKING SYMBOL character` (🚬)

(via this decoder: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder)

Comment: Just for the record, everything works correctly in python 3.5, even on my Mac.

Comment: I can confirm that my python is compiled with UCS-2, will revert back if it works when UCS-4 is used

Comment: @saulspatz as of Python 3.3 Unicode codepoints will never be broken up as UTF-16. See [PEP 0393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/).